# Отправка формы через Ajax в Dialog jQuery-UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Всем привет!
Есть форма с одним полем input-text.
Есть кнопка для отправки формы через ajax и она работает без проблем. Но при отправке данных нажатием на Enter с фокусом на текстовом поле вся страница перезагружается. А проблема в том, что весь сайт работает асинхронно (можно использовать только $.ajax) и перезагрузки не должно быть. В форме авторизации я использовал следующую функцию, которая работает:

```
$('#text').keypress(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        event.preventDefault();
        auth();
    }
});
```

А для отправки из Dialog не получается. Может можно хотя бы запретить отправку данных при нажатии на Enter? Главное, чтобы перезагрузки страницы не было.
Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Отменить событие по нажатию Enter можно как-то так

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('form').keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но всё равно не работает. Отменить получилось добавлением ещё одного текстового поля, которое я скрыл display: none; height: 0px; После этого хотя бы форма перестала обновлять страницу)

Comment: Пробовал проверить после этого, работает ли вообще функция по нажатию на клавишу, сколько пробовал, так и не заработало. Проверял на обычном alert(); И ничего...